# debugging a bad k8s deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment that fails within one second. And the logs are destroyed as the deployment does a rollback.

Is there anything similar to `logs -f` that works *before* a deployment have started and wait until it starts?

Comment: `kubectl logs --previous` to show the previous container's logs. If it's failing that fast, might be before logging happens

Comment: Sometimes it can help to `docker run` the same image locally.  This will help if the application is installed wrong, but not if the Kubernetes-specific command setup or environment variables are causing problems.

Answer (score 3):

Check previous logs with `kubectl logs -p <pod-name>` to spot application issues.

Also, check the exit code of your container with:

`kubectl describe pod <pod-name> | grep "Exit Code"`

Finally, if it is a scheduling problem, check out the event log of the corresponding ReplicaSet:

`kubectl describe replicaset <name-of-deployment>`